# Cocoa - Action every second

Tags: cocoa, nstimer, nstableview

How can I set action to update some information every 1 second?

I am creating chat (using social network API) and I have to check for new messages.

Comment: Does your API not have some sort of callback system to notify you of new messages? Waking your application once every second to check for a message even if none has arrived is not very power efficient

Comment: @iain: Not every system provides such calls to clients, so polling is still a necessary evil in many cases. This is a perfectly valid approach if the social network API doesn't give developers the opportunity to register for some sort of notification/callback.

Comment: Sure, I was just highlighting that if such a callback system existed it would be much better to use that than a naive system of polling every second which is going to be CPU and bandwidth heavy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare an instance of `NSTimer` in your .h file like this

`NSTimer *timer;`

then schedule it:

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 
                                         target:self   
                                       selector:@selector(checkForNewMessages) 
                                       userInfo:nil 
                                        repeats:YES];
```

When you don't need the timer anymore do this:

```
[timer invalidate];
 timer = nil;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also [use Grand Central Dispatch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/GCDWorkQueues/GCDWorkQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH103-SW2) for timed dispatches of blocks.